# Could it be a malware?

Tags: networking, malware

Something makes all browsers on any operating system or computer of my home network to open random web pages and ask to install a Microsoft protection of some kind, what could do that?

It send random links like:

- `http://results.google-analytics.com/`
- `http://wellaction.com/?q=fine+silverware`
  redirects to `http://crazyfastcash.com/?query=fine+silverware`

Comment: Are you saying that if you insert a live linux CD and boot from that , your web browser still offers to install microsoft protection?

Comment: Checked and does the same ...

Comment: are you connecting via wifi?  Does this happen if you plug directly into your modem or router?  Are you certain your not inadvertently roaming onto a neighbouring network?

Comment: it's my network, i'm on wifi upstair and I never use lan connection, my router is secured ...

Comment: Have you changed your WPA key, in case somebody managed to crack it and is messing with your network traffic somehow? Does it show any unexpected devices on the network?

Comment: Sounds like DNS hijacking to me, got nothing to do with any of your computers and probably doesn't even have anything to do with your computer. Try setting your DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 (secondary to 8.8.4.4) which are Google's DNS servers and should be safe. If it still continues to happen then it might be worth it contacting your ISP to figure this out with them (mention in full detail this happens across all OSes and all computers and you checked out the router).

Comment: DNS hijacking is a possibility, but I think it's unlikely an ISP's DNS server can be hit with DNS hijacking for any extended period of time. A more common scenarior to hijack website resolution, is ARP spoofing based malware, that will only affect the user's local network. The user just need to find out which computers have the malware, and clean it.

Comment: @KoKo To do that, he would have to start by disconnecting everything except one computer and then just keep connecting things until he sees the behavior? I've never heard of that before, very interesting.

Comment: @KoKo: +1 Hmm, also sounds like a possibility. If he's using WiFi then this might introduce a "slower internet" symptom due to the higher chance of collisions, as I've seen happen once. On a DD-WRT it might be possible to do a `tcpdump` and inspect that perhaps, other than that it's indeed going to be a tricky divide & conquer approach to finding the guilty computer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many trojans that try to duplicate the Microsoft Windows Update and Windows Defender UIs. They are especially effective if you run your browser full-screen; they really do look like the real thing. Also, Googling the name will not help because they use Microsoft's names and logos.

The best way to tell if it's a fake is to minimize the browser; if the "virus alert" disappears, it's a fake.

Microsoft has a web page showing some of these fake programs at http://www.microsoft.com/security/antivirus/rogue.aspx.

If you see one of these things, tell the web site.

Comment: this isn't a malware, it's more like a rootkit or an hijack,
it send links like http://results.google-analytics.com/ ...

Answer (score 1):

How do you connect to the internet?

Given it's any OS and all computers it sounds like there's something wrong with your router or gateway PC.

What's the URL of the site(s) you get? You can enter them as text if you don't want to link to them.

Comment: wifi ... I tried to upgrade the firmware of the router, I thinked the same as you for that ...

For websites examples, I will try to note some then add them here ...

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange that all OS are affected, so it must be something on your router or internet connection.

If you connect through a gateway computer you should restart the computer in safe mode and run antivirus and spyware to check for DNS changer viruses.

If you have a connection through a wireless router, it may be compromised. Try changing the password for the router and see if the problem continues.

Just to be safe I recommend scanning all the computers in your home for viruses.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to actually research the 'Microsoft protection' program that it's detailing. Try Googling the name of it to see if it's malware (note: it's best to go to recognisably named websites and look at any that are paid for at the top - they are usually reputable).

Though it sounds as if that if it is malware, it's something in your router, or maybe on a bit of hardware, like a shared USB key for it to be on more than one computer. Or maybe everybody went on the same website and got infected, but it does sound like malware at the moment, though you will have to research it more to properly find out

Comment: malware are uneffective on linux, rootkits are possibles but won't affect all os on many computers and browsers ...

Comment: an ARP spoofing malware installed on your windows machine, can still affect your linux machine or any other OS that is connected to your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ARP spoofing malware if it is affecting all computers on your network. First isolate the computer that is sending out the ARP attacks, then either wipe and re-install the OS clean or get a really good scanner that can detect ARP malware (I'd probably just wipe and re-install the OS).